# Status Bar Notification Not Showing?

Tags: android, notificationmanager

I have a simple method which onclick() of a Button should generate status bar notification, but for some reason, it isn't showing up.

```
public void createNotification() {
    NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
            .setSmallIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert)
            .setContentTitle("Notification!")
            .setContentText("This is my first notification!");
    Notification notification = builder.build();
    NotificationManagerCompat notificationManager = NotificationManagerCompat.from(this);
    notificationManager.notify(0, notification);
}
```

Comment: Can I see your `onClick()` method?

Comment: All it does is call this createNotification() function

Comment: I need to see it.

Comment: Try replacing your `setSmallIcon` with another drawable, like `R.drawable.icon`, not from the android resources.

Comment: FloatingActionButton fb = (FloatingActionButton) rootView.findViewById(R.id.addProfileButton);
        fb.setOnClickListener(
                new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        //TODO testing notifications
                        createNotification();
                    }

Comment: I tried changing the icon too and that didn't work.

Comment: Does the app actually crash?

Comment: When I stepped through my createNotification function I noticed that my variable notification has it's contentView = null. Could that potentially be the problem? And what could be causing that

Comment: Does the button show up in your Activity?

Comment: Yeah I can click on the button and it triggers my createNotification()

Comment: See my answer, I think the problem is in your NotificationManager.

Answer (score 6):

In Android 8 (API level 26), all notifications must be assigned to a channel. 
This work for me:

```
    NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(getContext(), CHANNEL_ID)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.emo_no_paint_120)
            .setContentTitle("title")
            .setContentText("content")
            .setColor(Color.parseColor("#009add"))
            .setAutoCancel(true);

    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getContext().getSystemService(
            NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        NotificationChannel mChannel = new NotificationChannel(CHANNEL_ID, CHANNEL_NAME, NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH);

        notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(mChannel);
    }

    notificationManager.notify(0, mBuilder.build());
```

And you should add AppCompat library

```
implementation 'com.android.support:support-compat:27.1.0'
```

You could check [official Android Docs](https://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/channels.html)

Answer (score 0):

Your code is okay. But since you are targeting Android 8.0, you need to implement Notification Channels since this the preferred way in Android Oreo.

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html

Comment: Unfortunately it still isn't working even with the NotificationManager change

Comment: Do you see a message if you add this in your onClick() method? Toast.makeText(this, "Clicked!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

Comment: Yes that shows up so I know its going into the function

Comment: Exactly, then that is fine. Dumb question; you never turned notifications off for your app? And, are you running Android 8.0?

Comment: Yeah I am running android 8.0 and notifications are turned on for my app

Comment: Allright. Please try to implement NotificationCompat with Notification Channels.

Comment: Good, if it answered your question, please mark it as answer.